# how do i get the exact 20 frames from 20 second rtsp stream?

Tags: python, opencv

here i trying to get exact 20 frames from 20 second rtsp stream. while try to write the frame it will only writing 12 frames from the 20 second of rtsp stream. aslo i try the pool.async method to write the operation separately. but im still getting only 12 frames from 20 second rtsp stream.

```
import threading
import cv2
import os,shutil,time
from datetime import datetime

root = os.getcwd()

def VideoCapture(url, name):
    count = 1
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    path = root + "/" + str(name)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    else:
        shutil.rmtree(path)
        os.mkdir(path)
    start = time.time()
    while vid.isOpened():
        vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, (count * 1000)) 
        ret, frame = vid.read()

        if ret:
            resize = cv2.resize(frame, (600, 400))
            filename = path + "/image_"+ str(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M- 
            %S"))+"%d.jpg" % count
            cv2.imwrite(filename, resize)
            count = count + 1

            cv2.imshow(str(name), resize)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

            check = time.time()
            if check - start >= 20:
                break
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Time Elapsed {end - start}")

arr = [{"name": "cam1", "url": r"rtsp://admin:Admin123$@10.11.25.64:554/stream1"},
       {"name": "cam2", "url": r"rtsp://admin:Admin123$@10.11.25.61:554/stream1"}]

for i in arr:
    url = i['url']
    name = i['name']
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=VideoCapture, args=(url, name,))
    t1.start()
```

Comment: I think  `vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,...)`  doesnt make sense. In a stream you typically can't change the position but you can only receive it frame by frame. Can you try to remove that line and instead add a print of `vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)` after vid.read() ? Can you, for debugging, remove the whole resizing, imshow and imwrite and observe how many frames are read within the 20 seconds and how their timestamps look like?

Comment: i got the  number of frames: 518 for Time Elapsed 20.02703595161438.

Comment: any idea  how can i write exact 20 second frame of the rtsp video?

Comment: can you print `vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)` (sorry, I'd written .set in the previous comment) and check whether the difference between subsequent frames is about 40 msec? If yes, just read a frame and read `vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)` and whenever 1 second after the last saved frame has passed, save the frame. After 20 saved frames, quit.